# Hidden folders in android

Tags: android

I had folder `main` on my android phone that contain another folder with the name '.test' then i copied the main folder to my laptop over the usb and didn't find the `.test` folder inside it.is there any way to recover or get it.

Comment: Try copy only .test folder then.

Comment: I couldn't find it from windows. when  i moved the `main` folder the inside hidden folder `.test` was deleted probably

Comment: Do you have es file explorer ... you can use that ... there is a option show hidden files ...it shows the hidden folders.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the `.test` folder or it's data  anywhere on the mobile or the laptop so i used recovery app `DiskDigger` to get the data from the phone after making root and i finally got it